# A duck gets it - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

When you do me upwards or downwards, you may end up in tears.
And being downwards is being told how 'it' is.
When you do me inwards you're in breech of the law.
You do me cleanly when you forget about before.
When I'm away, you'll make an exit.
Every time that's your first time, a duck gets it.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Break

When you do me upwards or downwards, you may end up in tears.

> A **break-up** is the end of a relationship. 
>  A **breakdown** is a sudden collapse in a person's mental health. 
>  Both are very sad.

And being downwards is being told how 'it' is.

> "Let me break it down" means to let me explain it in fundamental terms.

When you do me inwards you're in breech of the law.

> A **break-in** is an illegal forced entry to a building or vehicle.

You do me cleanly when you forget about before.

> A **clean break** is a complete separation that allows you to forget about before.

When I'm away, you'll make an exit.

> **Breakaway** is a divergence from something well established.

Every time that's your first time, a duck gets it.

> To **break one's duck** in cricket means to end a run of zeroes. As pointed out by Ankoganit, it also means to do something for the first time.

Comment: Break one's duck also means [to do something for the first time.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_one%27s_duck)

Comment: Correct! Well done. Line 3 has an added meaning too, to do with the answer and law :)